# What is the term for repeating non-restrictive clauses?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, clauses, repetition

I came across the following quote:

> Scientists would soon find themselves adrift in a bewildering realm of
> particles and antiparticles, where things pop in and out of existence
> in spans of time that make nanoseconds look plodding and uneventful,
> where everything is strange.

The sentence ends with two nonrestrictive clauses that each begin with "where." The second seems to emphasize the first.

Is there a name for this type of construction? I've seen this sort of repetition elsewhere in writing and speeches. Is it grammatically correct to string together--hypothetically--an unlimited number of nonrestrictive clauses so long as they build upon the main clause?

Comment: Sure, though it's mostly done in writing, or in oratory, because it's purple prose.